# Change URL in browser without redirection using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I have a URL **http://domain.com/foo/bar/100**. I want to remove **/foo/bar** from the URL without redirecting it.

Please help me with this problem as I am new for htaccess.

Comment: Please share your current htaccess config.

Answer (score -1):

1. is this URL created by .htaccess rules?
2. if not: change your document root or add a location directive to the server.

Comment: This URL is created using .htaccess